What does this change in org mode cursor display mean?
Using emacs 26.1 with org mode 9.1.9.
I sometimes by accident press C-RET and what happens is that my cursor changes from flashing yellow to alternating between flashing red and flashing yellow with a red line at the bottom.
Nothing else happens in the file.
So I thought I would look this up and found:
https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Editing.html

C-RET (org-insert-heading-respect-content)
Insert a new heading at the end of the current subtree.


But in my case a new heading is not inserted anywhere in my file.
What does this flashing cursor mean?
Why is it not inserting a new heading at the end of the current subtree?

I can't reproduce this behavior. Do you always get this behavior when your press C-RET or is it something that happens in specific situations? If the latter, please describe the situation as precisely as possible. If it always happens, I would suggest you start Emacs with emacs -Q: if  you cannot reproduce it there, then something is screwy with your init file (or the site-init file but that's less likely). Try bisecting your init file to finger the culprit.

The issue does not occur with emacs -Q so I will bisect my init file - thanks

Update - I bisected my .emacs file and found no issues with it. I was running on emacs 26.1 with org mode 9.1.9. It was fair to suggest maybe I was running old versions of emacs or org mode - I decided to change distros (this is why I have not updated earlier, this took some time) - Now at emacs 29.4 with org mode 9.5.15.

I also decided to re-create my .emacs file one step at a time, to see if that would maybe show the issue as I added more code to it. That did not help. LOL then I selected Options > [x] Cut/Paste with C-x C-c C-v and this caused the issue. @NickD - Maybe you could try to reproduce this - I am just curious to see what would happen. Thanks.
